# Reading from a file with empty line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently working on a program for one of my java class and I keep running into a wall with file reading! I am using a JTable to display the information so when the information is read from a file it is added to a row. Whenever there is a blank row the scanner cannot read it and throw an error! i get a java.util.NoSuchElementException on the last scanning line! As of right no i am suing two separate scanners. I had attempted to use the String.split method that that also gave me an error (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0). I will post the reading a saving methods below (both two scanner version and split).

private void read() {

```
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("games.dat"));


        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String[] tableRow = new String[6];
            Scanner recIn = new Scanner(record);
            recIn.useDelimiter("\\s*\\|\\s*");
            tableRow[0] = recIn.next();
            tableRow[1] = recIn.next();
            tableRow[2] = recIn.next();
            tableRow[3] = recIn.next();
            tableRow[4] = recIn.next();
            //recIn.next();
            recIn.close();
            model.addRow(new Object[]{tableRow[0],
     tableRow[1], tableRow[2],
     tableRow[3], tableRow[4]});
```

}scanner.close();
             scanner = null;

```
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Could not connect to file! Make sure you are not in        zipped file!",
                "Warning!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
}



private void save() {

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {


        String data = model.getValueAt(i, 0) + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 1)
                + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 2) + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 3)
                + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 4) + "|";
        games.add(data);
```

}

```
 try {
        for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {
            fileOut.println(games.get(i));
        }
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Could not connect to file! Make sure you are not in zipped file!",
                "Warning!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recIn.next();` will fail if the line is empty, guard it with `hasNext()`:

```
Scanner recIn = new Scanner(record); 
recIn.useDelimiter("\\s*\\|\\s*");
if (recIn.hasNext()) {
  tableRow[0] = recIn.next(); 
  tableRow[1] = recIn.next(); 
  tableRow[2] = recIn.next(); 
  tableRow[3] = recIn.next(); 
  tableRow[4] = recIn.next();
}
```

This assumes that when there is one element on the record, all of them are there.  If this cannot be guaranteed, you need to protect each `next()` call with `hasNext()` and decide what to do when you run out of elements in the middle of a record.

Also, you seem to have an infinite loop:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  // no calls to scanner.next()
}
```

Did you leave out `String record = scanner.next();` from the top of that loop?

Comment: yes I'm sorry i forgot to include that line of code in my original post

Comment: i've done what you suggested and now it works! but now when there is nothing in the delimited field it will print null to the table

Comment: put `model.addRow(new Object[]{tableRow[0], 
     tableRow[1], tableRow[2], 
     tableRow[3], tableRow[4]});` within the body of the guarding `if`, so you only add values to the table if you could parse them (note: the call to `recIn.close()` should be outside the `if`: you want ot close it whether you could read from it or not)  Also, if this solved your question, please accept my answer.

Comment: i still receive the null value when the program is exited. The output file gets one null value added to it every time it is saved. this is what the file looks like after being run, saved, and closed three times: 
|||null|null|
|||null|null|
|||null|null|
|||null|null|
|||null|null|

Comment: each of these: |||null|null| is on a new line

Comment: i was able to fix the null error. One last error to fix. Whenever the file gets save the fields get pushed over one to the left. So in the read it is getting taken is as element 0 when it should be 1!

Comment: Not sure I understand:  you read the file in, then save it and the file looks as you would expect.  Then you read this saved file and the first part of the record is not in the right position?  Can you post examples for a (small) input file that causes this problem?

Comment: Every time i save a file i execute this line of code
`String data = model.getValueAt(i, 0) + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 1)
                    + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 2) + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 3)
                    + "|" + model.getValueAt(i, 4) + "||";`

on the first save the file looks like this :

first||||||
|second|||||
||Disk||||
|||fourth|||
||||fifth||

each one is in it specified field.
upon reading the file the new table looks like this! 


first||||||
second||||||
|Disk|||||
||fourth||||
|||fifth|||

Comment: From the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) documentation: "_The next() and hasNext() methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as nextInt() and hasNextInt()) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token._"  So the first '|' at the beginning of the record is skipped when you call `next`.  You could prevent this by printing a dummy value if `model.getValueAt(i, 0)` returns an empty string, then check for the dummy value when you do the first recIn.next() and assign [cont]

Comment: [cont] the empty string ("") to `tableRow[0]` if recIn.next() returns the dummy value.  Make sure to select a dummy value that cannot be an otherwise valid value

Answer (score 1):

From the java.util.Scanner JavaDoc, there is this method, skip():

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29

The last line reads, "Note that it is possible to skip something without risking a NoSuchElementException by using a pattern that can match nothing, e.g., sc.skip("[ \t]*")."

So, perhaps add as the first call of your loop, scanner.skip("[ \t]*);